# Laravel: trim included template

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I have a template file called `include/data.blade.php` which ends with line feed in the end of the file. (It's IDE default configuration that I would not like to change)

The mentioned template is included in another template the following way:

```
# parent blade template
<script>
    let tpl = '@include("include.data")';
</script>
```

As `data.blade.php` ends with blank line, after template rendering I get a javascript error in browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The question is: can I in any way trim the included template?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution for laravel 5.6+.

1. Register a new `trim` blade directive in `AppServiceProvider::boot()`:

   ```
   //Register starting tag
   Blade::directive('trim', function() {
       return '<?php ob_start() ?>';
   });

   //Register ending tag
   Blade::directive('endtrim', function() {
       return "<?php echo trim(ob_get_clean()); ?>";
   });
   ```
2. Use registered directive as follows:

   ```
   # parent blade template
   <script>
       let tpl = '@trim @include("include.data") @endtrim';
   </script>
   ```